# php header('Content-type: image/jpeg') shows borken image

Tags: php, image, header, jpeg, content-type

I am trying to use an email address as an image.

I wrote the following code:

```
<?php 

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

echo $email= 'ali@alipakistani90.com';
echo $email_length= strlen($email);
echo $font_size= 4;

echo $image_height= imagefontheight($font_size);
echo $image_width= imagefontwidth($font_size) * $email_length;

$image= imagecreate($image_width, $image_height);

imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);

$font_color= imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);

imagestring($image, $font_size, 0, 0, $email, $font_color);

imagejpeg($image);

?>
```

I googled out and tried following solutions.

1. Gd p library is configured and working.
2. I cleared the browser cache.
3. I have check all function on php manual.

`Please Note: I also get broken image when I only the following code:`

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
```

My gd configuration:

`GD Support enabled
GD Version  bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
FreeType Support    enabled
FreeType Linkage    with freetype
FreeType Version    2.4.10
GIF Read Support    enabled
GIF Create Support  enabled
JPEG Support    enabled
libJPEG Version unknown
PNG Support enabled
libPNG Version  1.5.14
WBMP Support    enabled
XPM Support enabled
libXpm Version  30411
XBM Support enabled
WebP Support    enabled`

I appreciate your efforts.
Thanks

Comment: Are there any notices in your `php_error_log`? Maybe the `header(...)` doesn't work because headers are already sent (maybe because the server has already sent data to the client).

Comment: Remove all your `echo`s then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

As @Ultimaer mentioned, you should remove all your `echo`es. Your code is putting some information on top of your image data, that is probably why it looks broken.

Here's the working source:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

$email= 'test@test.com';
$email_length= strlen($email);
$font_size= 4;

$image_height= imagefontheight($font_size);
$image_width= imagefontwidth($font_size) * $email_length;

$image= imagecreate($image_width, $image_height);

imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);

$font_color= imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);

imagestring($image, $font_size, 0, 0, $email, $font_color);

imagejpeg($image);
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your help and suggestion. The code was perfect. But I was making a silly mistake. I added un-intentionally a vacant line at the starting of the php file which was creating problem. I removed that line and removed all echo & code started working.

Answer (score 0):

Remove echo keyword and try it.

```
$email= 'ali@alipakistani90.com';
$email_length= strlen($email);
$font_size= 4;

$image_height= imagefontheight($font_size);
$image_width= imagefontwidth($font_size) * $email_length;

$image= imagecreate($image_width, $image_height);

imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);

$font_color= imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);

imagestring($image, $font_size, 0, 0, $email, $font_color);

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

imagejpeg($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```